# wordpress JSON API Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <script

Tags: json, angularjs, wordpress

I am using the wordpress JSON API to make an android app with angularJS. I am using the following code, and everything works fine.

```
$http.jsonp(WORDPRESS_API_URL + 'get_post/' +
  '?post_id='+ postId +
  '&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
.success(function(data) {
  deferred.resolve(data);
})
.error(function(data) {
  deferred.reject(data);
});
```

But in some pages of my wp site I use the jplayer module, which places this code at the `<head>`

```
<script>
var MP3jPLAYLISTS = [];
var MP3jPLAYERS = [];
</script>
```

This    `<script>` tag comes along with the JSON return like this

```
<script>
 var MP3jPLAYLISTS = [];
 var MP3jPLAYERS = [];
</script>
angular.callbacks._2({"status":"ok","post": ....
```

which gives the Unexpected token

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You must build JSON API which will provide only JSON.

You have words `JSON API` in your question. API, answers of your API, must be JSON-valid. That means, that responses can only have headers and JSON data:

```
{"data": {"items": [1, 2, 3]}}
```

This is correct JSON.

In your case, response contains some HTML tags. It is not valid json, so your JSON request fails.

Comment: I haven't build a json API. I use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/. In some cases the JSON response is correct (without HTML tags) but in others I have this problem. From your answer I can undesrtand that there is something wrong in the API

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, not so elegant but it works. I am writting it here just in case someone has the same problem.
The problem arises by the jplayer module. So in main.php file of this module you can make the following change:

```
function defineJSvars ()
{
    if ( ! $this->JSvars ) {
        $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
        $pos = strpos($actual_link, "api/get_");

        if ($pos == ""){
            echo "\n<script>";
            echo "\nvar MP3jPLAYLISTS = [];";
            echo "\nvar MP3jPLAYERS = [];";
            echo "\n</script>\n";
        }
        $this->JSvars = true;
    }
}
```